# Gross Pay using Arrays (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a code to calculate the gross pay of seven employees using arrays. Here is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
//Set all constants and variables
const int SIZE = 7;             //Size of all arrays
int emID[SIZE] = {1234, 4563, 8765, 4568, 9867, 9235, 7684};

double  Hours[SIZE],
        Rate[SIZE],
        Gross[SIZE];

int index;

Gross[index] = (Hours[index] * Rate[index]);

//Explain Program
cout << "This program calculates an employees gross pay\n";

for (Hours[index];index <= 6; index++)
{
    cout << "How many hours did employee " << emID[index] << " work?\n";
    cin >> Hours[index];
}

for (Rate[index]; index <= 6; index++)
{
    cout << "Enter the pay rate for " << emID[index] << endl;
    cin >> Rate[index];
}

for (Gross[index]; index <=6 ; index++)
{
    cout << "The gross pay for " << emID[index] << " is " << Hours[index] * Rate[index];
}

}
```

Unfortunately the program terminates after the first "for" loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: **index** need to initialize.

Comment: `thats not how this works. Thats not how any of this works.` Please read up on the usage of a for loop once more.

Comment: This is my first programming class...

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a few mistakes in your code, which I'm pointing out below.

- `index` is unitialised, and the way you've used it results in Undefined Behavior. I think you meant to initialise to to 0.
- You should reset the value of `index` to `0` between `for` loops. Currently you would iterate in the first `for` loop. After that, since `index` will be `> 6`, your code will not execute the other two `for` loops.
- Your first term in the `for` loop declarations is wrong. I think you meant to declare `index = 0` there. If not, you should leave it empty.
- The line near the beginning where you calculate `Gross[index]` is wrong and redundant.

Comment: also gross array is not properly initialized and used, Additionally in loops index should not be used as array subscript.